# move-assigning a std::map with an aligned value type segfaults

Tags: c++, optimization, stl, segmentation-fault, clang++

The following code segfaults consistently for me on clang 3.8 but succeeds on clang 3.7. I compile with `clang++ -std=c++14 -O2 test_case.cpp -o test_case` in both cases. If I compile with optimisations off on clang 3.8 the program runs to completion.

I'm guessing that the compiler is taking some liberties when optimising - my question is: Is the compiler allowed to optimise in this way, or have I found my first compiler bug?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct __attribute__((aligned(16))) troublesome {
  float s;
};

int main() {
  std::map<int, troublesome> m{{0, troublesome{}}};
  std::map<int, troublesome> n{{1, troublesome{}}};
  std::cout << "GOT HERE" << std::endl;  //  always prints
  m = std::move(n);  //  segfault happens here
  std::cout << "GOT HERE TOO" << std::endl;  // only get here on old clang
}
```

Comment: In general, the standard library is not required to support over-aligned types.

Comment: You should file this at http://llvm.org/bugs

Comment: The just-approved draft of the upcoming C++17 standard adds support for proper dynamic allocation of over-aligned types. I'm not sure if structures containing such are required to respect that in general, and even if they did, whether they would get the new aligned allocators as well. Further, the definitions of standard library containers might need to be updated to provide that extra conformance.